# How to write SQL query to fetch the first record (latest) using IN clause?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have an excel file with some data in it (ids) and these id's have more than one record in the database. There are around 400 ids I have and I need to get the latest record for every id. I don't want to do it one by one. I tried using IN clause but it didn't work.

```
Select *
from myTable with (nolock)
where submission_number IN ('02597', '69875')
order by timestame DESC;
```

Above query doesn't work what I want. Can some please help/guide?

Thanks

Comment: Slight detour but an important one. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `apply`:

```
select t.*
from (values ('02597'), ('69875')) v(submission_number) cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.submission_number = v.submission_number
      order by t.timestamp desc
     ) t;
```

One nice feature is that you can use `outer apply`, which will return a row in the result set even when there is no match in your table.

Another method that doesn't use a subquery is;

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from myTable t
where submission_number in ('02597', '69875')
order by row_number() over (partition by submission_number order by timestame desc);
```

Comment: These queries are returning no results

Comment: @David . . . If your queries return results, these should as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` for that:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by submission_number order by timestame desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

This will return a single record for each `submission_number`.  If you only want the 2 in your `in` clause, you can add that back as `where` criteria.